# Python property and method override issue: why subclass property still calls the base class's method

Tags: python, inheritance, properties

Here is an example

```
class A(object):
        def f1(self):
                return []
        test1 = property(f1)


class B(A):
        def f1(self):
                return [1, 2]

if __name__ == "__main__":
        b = B()
        print b.test1
```

I expect the output to be [1, 2], but it prints [] instead.

It is contrary to my expectation.

Did I make any mistake in the code? If not, I suppose it works this way because when the property test1 is created, it is bound to the f1 function of the base class A. What is a possible alternative implementation to achieve what I want?

Comment: BTW, why CW for a perfectly technical question susceptible to sharp and equally technical answers?!  I responded before spotting the CW tag -- however, I loathe and usually avoid questions so wrongly labeled (CW when they obviously shouldn't be, or vice versa).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can defer the lookup of `f1` with a lambda function if you don't wish to pollute the class namespace

```
class A(object):

        def f1(self):
                return []

        test1 = property(lambda x:x.f1())
```

Answer (score 3):

> I suppose it works this way because
>   when the property test1 is created, it
>   is bound to the f1 function of the
>   base class A.

Exactly correct.

> What is a possible alternative
>   implementation to achieve what I want?

One more level of indirection:

```
class A(object):
    def f1(self): return []
    def _f1(self): return self.f1()
    test1 = property(_f1)

class B(A):
    def f1(self): return [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of alternatives I can think of: either repeat the call to `property` in the subclass,

```
class B(A):
    def f1(self):
        return [1,2]
    test1 = property(f1)
```

or base the property on another method which calls `f1`:

```
class A(object):
    def f1(self):
        return []
    def _f1(self):
        return self.f1()
    test1 = property(_f1)
```