# Is it Possible to rewrite the getter of a property in a subclass?

Tags: python, inheritance

For example:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = 0

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.v
    @value.setter
    def value(self, v):
        self.v = v

class SubExample(Example):
    pass
```

Would it be possible to rewrite just the getter to value in SubExample?

Comment: I fixed your code sample to make it valid Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do so like this

```
class DoubleExample(Example):
    @Example.value.getter
    def value(self):
        return self.v * 2

o = Example()
o.value = 1
print o.value # prints "1"

p = DoubleExample()
p.value = 1
print p.value # prints "2"
```

However, this only works if `Example` is a new-style class (`class Example(object):`) rather than an old style class (`class Example:`), as it is in your example code.

---

*Warning:* Thomas pointed out in the comments that this method may not behave as expected if you're using multiple inheritance (`class Foo(Bar, Baz)`).

Comment: Ah, this is what I wanted. I didn't know about this new/old class style thing, I'm still learning. Thanks. Also is there anywhere where I can learn more about using `@`?

Comment: Setters only work in new-style classes (which are classes that inherit, directly or indirectly, from `object`.) The problem with this solution is that it won't properly handle multiple inheritance situations, where some other class is between `DoubleExample` and `Example` in the inheritace hierarchy.

Comment: @ghasyx: To aid in your search, the name for a use of  `@` is "Decorator". The way they work is pretty simple: putting `@Example.value.getter` before the method is like putting `value = Example.value.getter(value)` after it. I'm afraid I don't know of a good resource for learning about them. Regarding new/old-style classes: I think that old-style classes are just for backwards compatibility, and you should always use new-style classes in code you write.

Comment: @Thomas: Could you provide an example of a situation where this would not work? I feel uncomfortable with its behaviour under multiple inheritance, but was unable to come up with a simple case where it failed.

Comment: a `SideExample` that inherits from `Example` and overrides the property, and a `DoubleSideExample` that inherits from `DoubleExample` and `SideExample` (in that order) that doesn't touch the property. The `DoubleSideExample` class would have most of the behaviour of `Example` modified by `SideExample`, but the property would completely ignore the `SideExample` class.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible to override a property's getter in a subclass, no. The property is an object that lives in the class and that holds references to the functions you give it -- if you later redefine the names of those functions, it won't affect the property at all.

What you *can* do is have the functions your property calls perform indirect calls, like so:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = 0

    @property
    def v(self):
       return self._v_getter()
    @v.setter
    def v(self, value):
       return self._v_setter(value)

    def _v_setter(self, value):
        self._v = value

class SubExample(Example):
    def _v_getter(self):
        return 5

>>> se = SubExample()
>>> se.v
5
>>> se._v
0
>>> se.v = 10
>>> se.v
5
>>> se._v
10
```

Alternatively, you can redefine the entire property in the subclass, by simply defining a new property. You won't have convenient access to the functions or property defined in the parentclass, however, and doing the right thing in the face of multiple inheritance is difficult.

Comment: Looks like you missed the underscore before your internal attribute name in your Example.__init__? Shouldn't you also have a placeholder _v_getter method defined in your base class too?

I did this in a base class where over-writing the properties getter is one of the primary uses of the class. The user can either set self.dloc = NPArray for a fixed value, or self.calc_loc = self.foo to override the properties getter method. The code that consumes the object just uses somenode.loc to request the value.

Comment: I didn't miss the underscore in `__init__`. The `__init__` method just assigns to the property, which means the actual property's setter is called. And yes, usually you want the baseclass to provide a minimal `_v_getter` as well. I don't remember why I didn't do this here.

Comment: Right! All the methods already exist at initialization so self.v calls self._v_setter even in __init__. Is it odd that I find that somewhat tricky? My immediate thought was that you were referencing an uninitialized variable _v...

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it would be tricky. `__init__` methods are called when instances of the class are created, which is by necessity after the class itself is created.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been answered before:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/408713-late-binding-properties-allowing-subclasses-to-ove/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393534/python-property-and-method-override-issue-why-subclass-property-still-calls-the

Essentially, instead of using `property` directly, you have to defer calling the getter so that it will access the one defined in the subclass rather than the one defined in the superclass when you first defined the property. This can be achieved via a `lambda`:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = 0
    def _value(self):
        return self.v
    def _value_setter(self, v):
        self.v = v
    value = property(lambda self: self._value(), lambda self, v: self._value_setter(v))

class Test2(Test):
    def _value(self):
        return self.v + 1

a = Test()
a.value = 2
print a.value  # 2

b = Test2()
b.value = 2
print b.value  # 4
```